# Number theory modular arithmetic how to account for adjustments

Tags: java, math, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am not sure whether my solution is justifiable (ans. 171) - Project Euler Q.19 since I am having a hard time getting my head around modular arithmetic and not really sure whether my approach to it was correct or not... I was having trouble on trying to get the equivalence of having 0 as a key rather than 1 to Monday for reference in a hash table. The question was;

> - 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> - Thirty days has September, April, June and November. All the rest    have thirty-one, Saving February alone, which has twenty-eight, rain
>     or shine. And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> - A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a    century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth
>   century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

So what I did was start the sum of days at 1 (reference for days in hash table) and subtract 1 after finding the sum of Sunday's, since doing it by 0 caused problems when the total sum of days were divisible by 3 and 6 (3:Wednesday, 6:Sunday). How could I have done this by using 0 as reference for Monday?

```
import java.util.*;

public class p19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable<Integer, String> days = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        days.put(1, "Monday");
        days.put(2, "Tuesday");
        days.put(3, "Wednesday");
        days.put(4, "Thursday");
        days.put(5, "Friday");
        days.put(6, "Saturday");
        days.put(7, "Sunday");

        Hashtable<Integer, String> months = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        months.put(1, "January");
        months.put(2, "February");
        months.put(3, "March");
        months.put(4, "April");
        months.put(5, "May");
        months.put(6, "June");
        months.put(7, "July");
        months.put(8, "August");
        months.put(9, "September");
        months.put(10, "October");
        months.put(11, "November");
        months.put(12, "December");

        int min, max;
        min = 1900;
        max = 2000;

        String[][] arr = new String[12 * (max - min + 1)][];

        // Total days starts at 1 to make modular arithmetic easier when accounting for days 
        // (i.e., 1 Monday, 2 Tuesday, etc.) and since the first day, hence, 0th day on 1 Jan 1900 is Monday.
        for (int year = min, index = 0, totalDays = 1; year <= max; year++) {

            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++, index++) {

                arr[index] = new String[numberOfDays(month,year)];

                int sum = 1;

                System.out.println(months.get(new Integer(month)) + " " + year);

                for (int day = 1; day <= numberOfDays(month, year); day++, totalDays++) {

                    if (totalDays % 7 == 0) {

                        arr[index][day - 1] = days.get(new Integer((totalDays % 7 + 7) % 365));                         
                    }
                    else {

                        arr[index][day - 1] = days.get(new Integer((totalDays % 7) % 365));                         
                    }

                    if (sum > 7) {

                        System.out.println();

                        sum = 1;
                    }

                    System.out.print(totalDays + ":= " + arr[index][day - 1] + ", " + day + " | ");

                    sum++;
                }

                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i][0] == "Sunday") {

                count++;
            }
        }
        // Subtract 1 from count since the total days were overstated by 1 before inititallizing array
        System.out.println("Number of Sundays that fell on the first of the month from: 1/Jan/1901 - 31/Dec/2000: " + (count - 1));
    }

    public static int numberOfDays (int month, int year) {

        int days = 0;

        switch (month) {
            case 7: 
            case 4: 
            case 6: 
            case 11:
                days = 30;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (isLeapYear(year)) {
                    days = 29;
                }
                else {
                    days = 28;
                }
                break;
            default: days = 31;
                break;   
        }

        return days;
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {

        return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand your approach. IMHO, you either take the first Sunday of 1901 and add +7 to each date, then check if the date is YYYY-MM-01. Or you take years from 1901-2000, months from 1 to 12, generate date y/m/01 and check whether it is sunday. So you tried to solve it without date/time-lib. But why do you need the month-names? And what are the names of weekdays for? And without using a date/time-lib, why do index days and months starting from 1, which is hard to get right with modulo operations?

Comment: Btw. here is a shell approach, but using a date function: `for x in {0..36525..7}; do date -d "6 Jan 1901 +$x days" | grep "So 1\." ; done | wc -l` **171** and here the other approch (So is sunday in my locale) `cnt=0; for y in {1901..2000}; do for m in {1..12}; do dow=$(date -d "$y-$m-01" +%a); if [[ $dow == "So" ]] ; then ((++cnt)); fi; done; done; echo $cnt` Result: **171**

Comment: I was not aware about date/time-lib until now, thanks. And I had a hard time visualizing so I made an array to print LOL.

Comment: Well, as exercise for modulo operation, it wasn't wasted time. And the java datetime library (java.util.Date) introduced an interface, where `getMonth` returned 0 for January, which worked fine with the other functions, but of course everybody expects 6 to refer to June. I guess the newer replacements avoided that trap, in which nearly every beginner stepped and even experienced programmers stepped into it, occasionally. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your daysInMonth check is incorrect - the result must have been correct by incidence:

```
switch (month) {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        days = 30;
        break;
```

The rest of the program can be simplified - note that the start year has to be corrected too, dow stands for DayOfWeek:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    // dow = 2, since 1.1.1901 was a Thuesday (2)
    for (int year = 1901, dow = 2; year <= 2000; ++year)
    {
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; ++month)
        {
            if (dow == 0) {
                // System.out.println ("Date: " + year + "-" + month);
                ++count;
            }
            dow = (dow + numberOfDays (month, year)) % 7;
        }
    }
    System.out.println ("Number of Sundays that fell on the first of the month from: 1/Jan/1901 - 31/Dec/2000: " + count);
}
```

Comment: Statement about off-by-one-error was wrong. Had the (count-1) in the println-statement :) .